# Can I reference Scrapy project in another project like multiple projects reference in c#?

Tags: c#, python, scrapy, pycharm

[reference Scrapy In Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhKX1.png)

**This is what I do**
1.create a new python project,create a new .py file;
2.reference Scrapy-master project(even I don't know how to do it);
3.write import in the new python file:
   from scrapy.selector import Selector
   from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
4.the IDE report unresolved reference error(of cause):
   and I don't know what to do to fix it.

Do I do the right thing ?  Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use/reference Scrapy in your project, your project's Python interpreter should be able to locate it. So install the Scrapy library and PyCharm will be able to load without an issue.

**Install using Pycharm Package Management**

You can install the package by going to `File | Settings | Project Interpreter`. Once there, follow the steps given in [PyCharm Help Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

**Install using Command Line**

You can install Scrapy using Pip:

```
pip install scrapy
```

Or if you want to use your copy of the downloaded *scrapy-master* for any particular reason, change directory to scrapy-master and run:

```
python setup.py install
```